# Taking the derivative of the integral of a tensor

Tags: calculus

This is a bit of a technical question. Say I had a tensor of some arbitrary rank, for the sake of this example I'll use a vector $V_i$. If I were to take the following integral:
$$\int V_i dx^i$$
And then differentiate with respect to $x^a$:
$$\frac{d}{dx^j}(\int V_i dx^i)$$
Will I just get back the original vector but with its $i$ index switched to a $j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, you should obtain:

$$V_{i}\delta_{j}^{i}$$

The book "Gauge fields, knots and gravity" by John Baez contains a good introduction to calculus on manifolds.